# What am I doing wrong in this Perl one-liner?

Tags: perl

I have a file that contains a lot of these

```
"/watch?v=VhsnHIUMQGM"
```

and I would like to output the letter code using a perl one-liner. So I try

```
perl -nle 'm/\"\/watch\?v=(.*?)\"/g' filename.txt
```

but it doesn't print anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `-n` option processes each line but doesn't print anything out. So you need to add an explicit `print` if you successfully match.

```
perl -ne 'while ( m/\"\/watch\?v=(.+?)\"/g ) { print "$1\n" }' filename.txt
```

Another approach, if you're sure every line will match, is to use the `-p` option which prints out the value of `$_` after processing, e.g.:

```
perl -pe 's/\"\/watch\?v=(.+?)\"/$1//' filename.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

Your regex is fine. You're getting no output because the `-n` option won't print anything. It simply wraps a `while (<>) { ... }` loop around your program (run `perl --help` for brief explanations of the Perl options).

The following uses your regex, but add some printing. In list context, regexes with the `/g` option return all captures. Effectively, we print each capture.

```
perl -nle 'print for m/\"\/watch\?v=(.*?)\"/g' data.dat
```

Comment: Is it worth adding a `\n` so that captures are separated?

Comment: @PP The `-l` option handles that.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string on `"="` instead of matching:

```
perl -paF= -e '$_= @F[1]' filename.txt
```